# PHP preg_match return false on check of space characters

Tags: php, regex

I need help with this regular expression check. I'm new to regular expressions so please bail me out. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to check if this date ranges both have months in their declaration e.g. `Feb 10 - Feb 12` is correct while `Feb 10 - 12` should fail. Also, some date instances may not have spaces between either the month and the day or the `-` and the month or date. Here's my code.

```
preg_match("/([A-Za-z]{3}\ *?\d{1,2}).*?\g{1}/", "Feb10 -feb 13")
```

but it keeps failing.

Comment: Seems like you want [`([A-Za-z]{3}\ *?\d{1,2}).*?(?1)`](https://regex101.com/r/9t9ugb/1). Did you try to use a subroutine rather  than a backreference?

Comment: Try [`([A-Z]{3} *\d{1,2}) *- *(?1)`](https://regex101.com/r/3xCJ3l/1)

Comment: Thanks guys, both solutions work.

Comment: I think regex is the wrong tool for your task. What about `XYZ 12 - abc 34` ? Are these good dates?. Find a way to split the range into two strings. Remove any space. Then simply `$d=date_parse_from_format( "Mj","Feb10");`

Answer (score 0):

As per my original comment below the question.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/3xCJ3l/1)

```
([A-Z]{3} *\d{1,2}) *- *(?1)
```

- `([A-Z]{3} *\d{1,2})` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `[A-Z]{3}` Match any 3 uppercase ASCII letters. Adding the `i` flag allows us to also match lowercase variants
  - `*` Match any number of spaces
  - `\d{1,2}` Match one or two digits
- `*` Match any number of spaces
- `-` Match this literally
- `*` Match any number of spaces
- `(?1)` Recurse the first subpattern